# creating a google cloud vm instance based on a docker image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a web site working with google cloud and am using a google managed ssl cert for a web site hosted on google domains. The vm just runs a small go web server.  [I wanted to test setting up a google managed certificate with instance groups & load balancers] All of that seems to work fine.  My issue is when the image changes. [because of an update to the site]

I have to delete and and re add the vm to get it to use the new image.

That does not seem right; so it there a different way to do this?

I would be ok with an edit to the vm and a restart; not sure if there is a better way or not...

Comment: have you check this [Google cloud compute instance update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912659/google-cloud-compute-instance-update)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it keeps the old container running unless you ssh in stop and remove the image & container and start a new one from the new image.  A few steps, but better than a delete an re create of the vm.  Not sure it the best way but it works.  I did not realize the vm keeps the old image around.  Makes sense once you know.